# Difference between linear regression and gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning

based assignment and I chose machine learning as my topic. I'm still in highschool so I don't know much about calculus.

My end goal is to try using a machine learning algorithm to predict stock values. But I want to understand what I'm doing without copying and analyzing existing codes that perform my required function.

This also isn't programming-related but mostly concerns over the theory part of it? I read through articles on linear regression and watched the lecture that Stanford has on its youtube. But I don't get it. These are my main confusions:

1. Are linear regression and gradient descent different algorithms or a set of algorithms used together to predict or classify stuff?
2. Are y = mx + c and f(x) = ϴ0 + ϴx same? What can I calculate with this?
3. This equation is shown in the linear regression part so what exactly does this do?
   [image]

Comment: A wrong platform for questions based on methodology. Kindly look at what sort of questions should be asked. As for this question, linear Regression is just a model/technique of regression where as Gradient Descent is the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer all three questions you asked.

First, let me classify ML into some categories.

1. Regression - Predicting continuous valued output (example, stock prediction)
2. Classification - Predicting discrete valued output (example, spam classification)

Now regression can be also classified as linear regression or polynomial regression.
Linear Regression is the simplest one. This is how it works.

Suppose I have this data.

[image]

These are the house prices plotted against size of the house. Now I want a straight line that can best fit this data. Maybe I will try this line.

[image]

And I will try more and more lines to see which actually fit best to the data. Now, to obtain different lines I will vary parameters like `a` and `b` in `y=a+bx`. This answers your second question, this equation represents a straight line which you are trying to fit to the data.

But, how will I decide if one line is better fit than the other. I will calculate some value which represents the error my line makes in correctly predicting the `y` values of all the `x` values in my data. This is actually called cost function. I can choose a cost function like this : [image]
(Ignore if it doesn't make sense).

But basically I want my cost function (error representing value) to be minimum and Gradient Descent is one such algorithm that can minimize my cost function. Gradient Descent can actually minimize any general function and hence it is not exclusive to Linear Regression but still it is popular for linear regression. This answers your first question.

Next step is to know how Gradient descent work. This is the algo:
[image]

This is what you have asked in your third question. This is the line of code which actually adjusts your fitting line(called hypothesis) while minimizing the cost function.

Comment: It's good that you write answers but answering a methodology-based question on SO won't be good for the platform as It will increase the likelihood of these questions being asked again.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat Yes I get it. Should I remove this?

Comment: Better that way. I would recommend answering such questions in the comment if you really want to.